# value in array concatenation with string not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In the following code, I want to concatenate the data in array `arr1` with string value in variable `t`.

```
var t:String;
var arr4:Array = new Array();
for(w;w<i;w++){
    if(max==arr3[w]){
    t=t.concat(",",arr1[w])
    }
}
trace(t);
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at final1_fla::MainTimeline/modebtn()

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is StackOverflow a modern version of [Rubber Duck Debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Answer (score 2):

That code doesn't make sense at all, arr4 is initialized but never used, instead arr3 and arr1 is used which might not be initialized and causing the null object reference error.

Your loop is using `w` which is not initialized and is comparing against `i` which isn't shown here.

Make sure your arrays are valid and check if that for loop is functioning as you expect it to.

Comment: sorry about that. arr3,arr1,w,i initialized in top in my original coding. but i only paste this concatenate part only. is this concatenate code OK

Comment: if arr3 and arr1 are valid arrays and if w isn't going out of bounds it is, `Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference` means something isn't initialized but it is being accessed. Debug and see the value of `w` and what it is accesing in those arrays.

Comment: I use trace(arr1[w]); in that place and I got my output. i want to take this output in one sting.
if(max==arr3[w]){
    trace(arr1[w]);
    }